# How to make nested for loop in R writing output to dataframe more efficient?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, coding-efficiency

I'm an R and stackoverflow noob - so please forgive if the question is not appropriate, or not really well structured.

I'm trying to write some R code to transform an nrow x ncol table/dataframe into a dataframe with each row comprising: RowNumber, Column Number, Value from column *j*, row *i* of the original table/dataframe.

I have a number of tables/dataframes that I want to do similarly with, which each have different numbers of rows, columns...

So I have, in this example, a 6 row by 9 column dataframe, that I want to convert into a dataframe with 54 rows:

```
#create example data
values <- rnorm(54, mean = 75, sd=3)
table_m <- matrix(values, ncol=9)
table <- as.data.frame(table_m)
```

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
##count rows and columns
nrows <- nrow(table)
ncols <- ncol(table)

#set up empty matrix for output
iterations <- nrows * ncols 
variables <-   3
output <- matrix(ncol=variables, nrow=iterations)

#set up first empty vector
my_vector_1 = c()

#run first nested for loop to create sequence of nrow * copies of column numbers
for (j in 1:ncol(table)) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(table))
  {
    my_vector_1[length(my_vector_1)+1] = colnames(table)[j]
  }

# add to first column of output
output[,1] <- my_vector_1

# set up second empty vector
my_vector_2 = c()

#run second nested for loop to create sequence of ncol * copies of row numbers
for (j in 1:ncol(table)) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(table))
  {
    my_vector_2[length(my_vector_2)+1] = rownames(table)[i]
}

# add to second column of output
output[,2] <- my_vector_2

#create third empty vector
my_vector_3 = c()

#run third nested for loop to pull values from original table/dataframe
for (j in 1:ncol(table)) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(table))
  {
    my_vector_3[length(my_vector_3)+1] = table[i,j]
  }

output[,3] <- my_vector_3
```

So, this code works, and does what I need...but in my noob state it was cobbled together from lots of Googling, and seems pretty inelegant.  In particular, creating intermediate vectors, and then assigning these to the output dataframe columns seems a bit cumbersome - but I couldn't get it to work trying to put the values straight into the columns of my output dataframe.

Any thoughts on how to improve the code, would be very welcome.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Similar to Ben's answer you can do `table %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -row)` Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

Comment: @RonakShah You might want to add `library(tidyverse)` /edit: obsolete after your edits

Comment: This is a common "mistake" when learning R, and often it comes from the belief that `data.frame`s in R behave similar to 2-dim arrays or tables in other languages. It doesn't. Very rarely is a `for` loop the most efficient way to change data in a frame, and (just about) never is it a good idea to iteratively, row-by-row, grow a frame.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah for the simplest solution!  Thanks also@r2evans for helpful comments. Really appreciate the community support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a nice way of doing it, but it's certainly possible in a shorter manner.
Try:

```
table$id <- 1:nrow(table) # Create a row no. column
tidyr::pivot_longer(table, cols = -id)
# A tibble: 54 x 3
      id name  value
   <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 V1     70.3
 2     1 V2     72.8
 3     1 V3     76.1
 4     1 V4     73.1
 5     1 V5     71.9
 6     1 V6     73.8
 7     1 V7     76.4
 8     1 V8     74.1
 9     1 V9     75.5
10     2 V1     73.8
# ... with 44 more rows
```

What are we doing here?

First of all, we add the "rownames" as column to the data (because for some reason, you want to keep them in the resulting data frame.
Then, we use the `pivot_longer()` function from the `tidyr` package. What you want to do with the data is reshaping. There are many possibilities to do so in R, (`reshape()`, the `reshape2` library, or the functions `pivot_longer()`, `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr`.

We want to have our "wide" data in "long" form (you may want to have a look at [this Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/data-import.pdf), even though the functions `gather()` and `spread()` are superseded by `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()`, but they basically function in the same way.

With the function argument `cols = -id`, we specify that all variables but `id` should come up in the value column of the new data frame.

If you want to have a matrix as your result, just run `as.matrix()` on the newly created object.

Comment: Many thanks @Ben.  I have accepted your answer as it is the one I intuitively understand, and you have provided a thorough explanation.  Thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
data.frame(c(t(df)))
```

If we want to know which V vector the value belonged to in the original data.frame:

```
data.frame(var = paste0("V", seq_along(df)), val = c(t(df)))
```

And also including the row index:

```
transform(data.frame(var = paste0("V", seq_along(df)), val = c(t(df)), stringsAsFactors = F),
          idx = ave(var, var, FUN = seq.int))
```

A more robust solution (given @r2evans reasoning):

```
transform(data.frame(var = names(df), val = do.call("c", df), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL), idx = ave(var, var, FUN = seq.int))
```

Another more robust solution using `stack()`:

```
transform(data.frame(stack(df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL),
          idx = ave(as.character(ind), ind, FUN = seq.int))
```

29/12/2020 Edit:
Robust solution mirroring @Ben's but in Base R:

```
transform(data.frame(name = as.character(rep(names(df), nrow(df))), value = c(t(df)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE), id = ave(name, name, FUN = seq.int))
```

Most straightforward Base R solution (mirroring Ben's answer):

```
# Flatten the data.frame: 
stacked_df <- setNames(within(stack(df), {
  # Coerce index to character type (to enable counting):
  ind <- as.character(ind)
  # Issue a count to each ind element: 
  id <- ave(ind, ind, FUN = seq.int)
  }
  # Rename the data.frame's vector match Ben's accepted solution:
), c("value", "name", "id"))

# Order the data.frame as in Ben's answer: 
ordered_df <- with(stacked_df, stacked_df[order(id), c("id", "name", "value")])
```

Data:

```
values <- rnorm(54, mean = 75, sd=3)
table_m <- matrix(values, ncol=9)
df <- as.data.frame(table_m)
```

Comment: This works only so long as all data in a frame is of the same class (e.g., `numeric` or `character`), and assumes that there are no additional columns (that a pivot/reshape would preserve).

Comment: @r2evans True, it was based only on the sample data provided by OP, but I understand it may not be generic enough for the actual data OP wants to apply it to. `reshape()` Would be a better choice in this case.

Comment: Thanks @hello_friend I'll have to work through your solution to fully understand what it is doing, but nice to have a base R solution as well.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Braveheart11971 please use upvote my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Hi @hello_friend I have upvoted your answer.  
When reviewing closely though I discovered that it wasn't doing quite what I needed (as _index_ was effectively just re-creating _var_, rather than indexing row numbers.

The codes, in my answer below, based on your suggested solution works.  Would be interested in your comments to decrease number of steps, simplify if possible.

Comment: @Braveheart1971 Thank you for upvoting. I'm not sure I entirely understand your question. From what I understand you have an issue with how I have rebuilt what is referred to in @Ben's solution as the `name` vector. Please see the two additional solutions above (which I have added in as an edit with today's date).

Comment: @hello_friend thanks for revisiting.  Your transform solution now does exactly what I need, with the slight addition of as.numeric() to the creation of id - to allow easier sorting.

Comment: @hello_friend I added: df_3 <- df_2[with(df_2, order(name, -id)), ] to get the output in the final form I needed.

The only bit of the code I struggled with is the ave() function - I think the name is throwing me.  Essentially the code creates sub-sets of _name_, grouped by _name_, and creates a sequence, incrementing for each sub-group of _name_ ?

Thanks again, I've learned so much from working through this!

Comment: @Braveheart1971 yes ave() is assigning a counter based on the id’s values. You could try merging your ordering function and mine to condense the code a bit further. Happy new year to you and yours!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @hello_friend's suggested answer above, I was able to come up with this solution in base R:

```
##Set up example data
values <- rnorm(54, mean = 75, sd=3)
table_m <- matrix(values, ncol=9)
df <- as.data.frame(table_m)

##Create intermediate vectors
total_length <- nrow(df)*ncol(df)
statment_count <- rep(seq_along(1:nrow(df)),each =ncol(df), length.out=total_length)
site_count <- rep(seq_along(1:ncol(df)),length.out=total_length)
value = c(t(df))

##join vectors into data frame
output <- data.frame(site = site_count, 
                     statement = statment_count,
                     value = value  
                     )

##sort output                    
output <- output[with(output, order(site, -statement)), ]
```

This is certainly far simpler and more intuitive to understand than the series of for loops I originally used.  Hopefully this will help someone else who is looking for a base R solution to a similar problem.

Also, for completeness, have added the 'full' solution for the tidyverse solution proposed by @Ben and @Ronak Shah

```
##Set up example data
values <- rnorm(54, mean = 75, sd=3)
table_m <- matrix(values, ncol=9)
table <- as.data.frame(table_m)

output_2 <- table %>% 
            mutate(statement = row_number()) %>%
            pivot_longer(cols = -statement)%>%
            rename(site = name)%>%
            relocate(site) %>%
            mutate(site = as.numeric(gsub("V", "", site))) %>%
            arrange(site, desc(statement))
```